# When using jQuery Mobile, how do I handle styling when JavaScript is disabled?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm playing with jQuery Mobile (1.1.0 RC1) because it basically does all the work of making my website look nice on mobile devices.

What am I supposed to do if javascript is disabled? I'm still new to HTML5, but my understanding is that the styling is based on the `data-*` attributes and without jQuery being able to read which theme/role it needs, no styling can be applied.

I can't find a default stylesheet that I can just apply, and the Theme Roller doesn't give a base swatch. Does jQuery Mobile have any kind of fallback for this, or do I need to write a custom set of stylesheets myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery Mobile only really works well on browsers that support jQuery.  Otherwise, the [grading system](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) kicks in and your app will degrade.  Consider applying a custom stylesheet in a `<noscripts>` tag for those users.

```
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your-non-jqm-css.css" />
</noscript>
```

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Comment: As someone who sucks at web design, I was hoping this wouldn't be the case. Ah well, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Surfing to http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/ with javascript disabled (in my laptop browser) results in a blank screen. With javascript enabled it looks solid though. Going to http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/index.html with javascript disabled atleast gives me the basic site.

I guess you'll need to provide your own basic mobile css if you need to support mobile browsers with javascript disabled.